# make multithreaded build with one recipe?

Tags: multithreading, makefile

If I have something like the following

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

and I run make with `-j`, will make do a multithreaded build? I've read the documentation for `-j`, and it says it will run multiple recipes in parallel. In my example, there seems to only be one recipe, but I'm not sure if make will do a multithreaded build anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one rule, but it's a *pattern rule*.  A pattern rule provides a "template" for make to know how to update any `.o` file based on its counterpart `.c` file.

So if you want to build 10 object files from 10 source files, make will apply this pattern rule to each one to build it.  If you use `-j10`, then make will invoke all the recipes in parallel since they don't depend on each other.

Comment: In the past, `make -j` (without the job number) would grind a Linux machine to halt with my non-recursive makefiles.

Comment: It will definitely still do that if you have lots of things to build.  Recursive vs. non-recursive is not really relevant, unless you're hard-setting `-j` when you invoke sub-makes.  Plain `-j` with no values was originally intended to be used in conjunction with the `-l` option, although that itself does have some downsides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is run with the number of jobs you pass to the `-j` parameter (e.g. number of processors on your machine plus one seems to be a good value). This rule will most likely consume most of the build time in larger projects, you should be able to see a considerable speed-up when compared to a `-j1` run.